# Does '&' perform parallel or linear jobs in linux shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, parallel-processing

I was trying to search online but didn't get a definite answer for this. Does the symbol `&` in linux perform two jobs in parallel or in a linear way?

for example:

```
command1 & command2
```

Here, will command1 and command2 be performed in parallel or will command2 be performed AFTER command1 finishes? What is exactly happening here?

The reason I'm asking this is because in my command1 and command2 I am calling scripts with different arguments which write some data to the same text file. After running the aforementioned script, I see that the output of command2 is being appended to command1. Is this the expected behaviour if they are truly working in parallel?

Comment: `c1 & c2` runs c1 and places it in the background, then starts running c2. It's not exactly "parallel", just two completely separate processes.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am trying to run heaving scripts in my c1 and c2 so in order to reduce the time I am trying to use &. Is this the best method?

Comment: "Best" depends on the details (and if you ask a question about "best" without specifying such details, it'll likely get closed as vague or subjective), but it's an easy and accessible method. Also consider `xargs -P` and GNU parallel (though I personally suggest caution around the latter -- it's a huge mess of code with enough complexity that I find it hard to trust).

Answer (score 1):

Try this on for size:

```
$ ls & pwd
[1] 7592     <---"ls" being put in the background as job #1, with pid 7592
/home/marc   <--- output of "pwd"

$ stuff
^---------------- shell waiting for next input
  ^^^^^---------- output of "ls" command
```

`a & b` places the `a` program in the background, and immediately starts executing the `b` command as well. It's not exactly parallel, but it is two completely separate processes that happen to be sharing a common output: your terminal

Comment: How does this method compare against parallel processing?

Comment: I am trying to run heaving scripts in my c1 and c2 so in order to reduce the time I am trying to use &. Is this the best method?

Comment: if you don't need to execute them serially, then `c1 & c2 &` would run BOTH in the background and free up your terminal again. `c1 & c2` would execute c1 in the backgroun and execute c2 in the foreground, tying up your terminal.

Comment: can't answer if it's any better, since you've provided no details about either job. but if c2 depends at all on anything c1's doing, then you're not going to gain much (if any) time savings, since c2 should be waiting for c1 to finish in the first place. if they can run completely independently of each other, then yes, you will MAYBE see some savings.